# Upgraded EF Core to 3.1 and got compilation error for Task.WhenAll

Tags: entity-framework, task-parallel-library, ef-core-3.1, valuetask

In our project we used EF Core 2.2.6. But after upgrading to EF Core 3.1, the following piece of code stopped compiling and giving an error

```
var offerTask = DbContext.Offers.FindAsync(offerId);
var priceTask = DbContext.VendorPrices
                         .Where(x => x.OfferId == offerId && ...)
                         .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
await Task.WhenAll(offerTask, priceTask);
```

> Error CS1503
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

I found out that in new version of EF Core, `FindAsync` method returns `ValueTask` (though in older version it returned `Task`), and this is causing the compilation error.

What is the workaround for this issue? Should I just use `.AsTask()`?

Comment: Yes, you should use `.AsTask()` when passing `offerTask` to `WhenAll`. But note that the code is incorrect, since it starts two tasks simultaneously on the same db context instance, which is not supported. So in case `offerTask` is not complete at the time you call `ToListAsync()` for starting the `priceTask`, you'll get runtime exception. The code "works" only if `FindAsync` is fast enough. You'd better `await` each async call and remove the need of variables and `WhenAll` call.

Answer (score 0):

[Ef core 3.1 breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#rtnt) :

> **Why**
>
> This change reduces the number of heap allocations incurred when
> invoking these methods, improving general performance.
> Applications simply awaiting the above APIs only need to be recompiled.

> **Mitigations**
>
> Applications simply awaiting the above APIs only need to be recompiled -no source changes are necessary. A more complex usage (e.g. passing the returned `Task` to `Task.WhenAny()`) typically require that the
> returned `ValueTask<T>` be converted to a `Task<T>` by calling `AsTask()` on
> it. Note that this negates the allocation reduction that this change
> brings.

**Solution:**

```
await Task.WhenAll(offerTask, priceTask).AsTask();
```